# Ordinal string compare in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In javascript:

```
"Id".localeCompare("id")
```

will report that "id" is bigger. I want to do ordinal (not locale) compare such that "Id" is bigger. This is similar to String.CompareOrdinal in C#. How can I do it?

Comment: Um, just use the regular `>` and `<` operators? (By the way, in an ordinal compare, `il` is bigger than `Id` because `i` is U+0069 and `I` is U+0049).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Raymond noted (and explained) in a comment, an "ordinal" non-locale aware compare is as simple as using the various equality operators on strings (just make sure *both* operands are strings):

```
"a" > "b" // false 
"b" > "a" // true
```

To get a little fancy (or don't muck with [[prototype]], the function is the same):

```
String.prototype.compare = function (a, b) {
    return ((a == b ? 0)
        ? (a > b : 1)
        : -1)
}
```

Then:

```
"a".compare("b") // -1
```

Happy coding.

Comment: The code provided has two errors: `(a > b : 1)` is a syntax error. Also, when using String.prototype, it makes sense to accept only one argument (the other string). The correct code is: `String.prototype.compare = function (other) {
    return (this == other ? 0 :
        (this > other ? 1 : -1));
}`

Answer (score 5):

I support the answers given by Raymond Chen and pst. I will back them up with documentation from my favorite site for answers to JavaScript questions -- The Mozilla Developer Network. As an aside, I would highly recommend this site for any future JavaScript questions you may have.

Now, if you go to the MDN section entitled [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings), under the section "Comparing strings", you will find this description:

> C developers have the strcmp() function for comparing strings. In JavaScript, you just use the less-than and greater-than operators:

```
var a = "a";  
var b = "b";  
if (a < b) // true  
  print(a + " is less than " + b);  
else if (a > b)  
  print(a + " is greater than " + b);  
else  
  print(a + " and " + b + " are equal.");
```

> A similar result can be achieved using the localeCompare method inherited by String instances.

If we were to use the string "Id" for `a` and "id" for `b` then we would get the following result:

```
"Id is less than id"
```

This is the same result that Yaron got earlier when using the `localeCompare` method. As noted in MDN, using the less-than and greater-than operators yields similar results as using `localeCompare`.

**Therefore, the answer to Yaron's question is to use the less-than (<) and greater-than (>) operators to do an ordinal comparison of strings in JavaScript.**

Since Yaron mentioned the C# method `String.CompareOrdinal`, I would like to point out that this method produces exactly the same results as the above JavaScript. According to the [MSDN C# documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/af26w0wa.aspx), the `String.CompareOrdinal(String, String)` method "Compares two specified String objects by evaluating the numeric values of the corresponding Char objects in each string." So the two String parameters are compared using the numeric (ASCII) values of the individual characters.

If we use the original example by Yaron Naveh in C#, we have:

```
int result = String.CompareOrdinal("Id", "id");
```

The value of `result` is an `int` that is less than zero, and is probably `-32` because the difference between "I" (0x49) and "i" (0x69) is `-0x20 = -32`. So, lexically "Id" is less than "id", which is the same result we got earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: by inverting case on all letters?

Answer (score 0):

```
function compareOrdinal(ori,des){
    for(var index=0;index<ori.length&&index<des.length;index++){
        if(des[index].charCodeAt(0)<ori[index].charCodeAt(0)){
            return -1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(parseInt(index)===des.length-1){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

compareOrdinal("idd","id");//output 1
```

Answer (score -1):

if you need to compare and find difference between two string, please check this:

```js
function findMissingString() {
    var str1 = arguments[0];
    var str2 = arguments[1];
    var i = 0 ;
    var j = 0 ;
    var text = '' ;
    while(i != (str1.length >= str2.length ? str1.length : str2.length )) {
        if(str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {
            i+=1 ;
            j+=1;
        } else {
            var indexing =  (str1.length >= str2.length ? str1.charAt(i) : str2.charAt(j));
            text = text + indexing ;
            i+=1;
            j+=1;
        }
    }
    console.log("From Text = " + text);
}
findMissingString("Hello","Hello world");
```

Comment: This is not a constructive answer.