# Where and how should I extend the String prototype in an Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to extend the String prototype and use it in one or more components of my Angular 5 application. The main reason is that I have a series of objects, which have properties that sometimes are populated, and sometimes not. Example: `customer.address` is sometimes a `string` (the `_id` of the address) and sometimes it's populated and it's an `Address` object, with an `_id` property.

What I want is basically not have to worry whether customer.address is populated or not, and simply access the `_id`. I know it's considered a Javascript anti-pattern according to some other responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630632/react-where-to-extend-object-prototype), but I thought of doing something like this:

```
String.prototype._id = function () {
    return String.prototype.valueOf()
}
```

Regardless of how bad of an idea this is -already answered in other questions-, would this be a way of doing it, and where should I declare this? Is there a better way of solving this issue?

Thanks.

PS. I know I could also overwrite the `toString` method in my `Address` class and get a similar result, calling `customer.address.toString()` to get the `_id`, but I feel like it's not legible and I'd like to explore other options first.

Comment: I still think you should not do it at all :-) But if you insist, you probably want a [getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592753/how-to-define-setter-getter-on-prototype) and not a function being added to `String.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will most likely not do it, but I am still curious as what would be the best way and what would be the downsides. In the end, maybe I'll just create some sort of utility function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/cM-qz3iyMIE) and my experience I would advise your to put like this, if your application is `AngularJS`:

```
yourApp.run(function() { 
   String.prototype._id = function () {
     return String.prototype.valueOf()
   } 
});
```

For Angular 2+ you can check [this](https://codepunk.io/extending-strings-and-other-data-types-in-typescript/) and check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript) that tells you how to extend String properties on Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which wraps your object and provides a means to catch missing values and much more.

The example below shows how the desired functionality can be achieved without having to extend any built-in types.

```js
let customer1 = {
  address: 'some string'
}

let customer2 = {
  address: {
    _id: '12345'
  }
}


let proxyCustomer = customer => new Proxy(customer, {
  get: (target, name) => {
    // define the properties to catch and their functions
    let propHandlers = {
      address: () => {
        a = target.address
        // decide what you want to do
        // in this example a string value is returned as a dummy object with an _id.
        return typeof a === 'string' || a instanceof String ?
          {_id: a} : a
      }
    }

    // default action - return prop
    let def = () => target[name]

    // assign function to handleProp if it exists or use the default (return named prop)
    let handleProp = propHandlers[name] || def

    // return result of handle call
    return handleProp();
  }
})

// wrap customer objects in proxy
customer1 = proxyCustomer(customer1)
customer2 = proxyCustomer(customer2)

// test
console.log(customer1.address._id)
console.log(customer2.address._id)
```